# Visual Studio C# watch variable representation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class that might have many fields, but in order to identify it in the debugger I am only interested in its `Name` property. Is there a way to display its name in the watches while debugging in Visual Studio other than modifying Autoexp.dat?

Is Visual Studio maybe looking for certain fields/functions to derive a string representation similar to how Eclipse does it in Java (it uses the result of the `toString()` method as representation in the debugger)?

Comment: Simply add a watch to `theInstance.Name`. I can´t see the problem.

Comment: Does adding a watch for `variable.Name` work?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree that this would be a valid solution if I am just looking for a single instance. However instances of this class might be contained in other classes and when I look at those containing classes in the the watch, it would be way easier to see the `Name` directly. Keep in mind that this is also a simplified example. The value I am looking for might also be derived from several fields.

Comment: Then you override ToString, yes, or add a [`DebuggerDisplay("...")]` attribute to the type.

Comment: If you can't or won't do that, there are 3rd party addons, like OzCode, that can do some of that stuff without modifying the types as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good way to do that is to use `DebuggerDisplay` attribute:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Name = {Name}")]
class Data {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now your watch will display `Name = valueOfName` for instance of given class. It's in general better than overriding `ToString` (which also works), because overriding `ToString` affects more than just debugging display, and you might not want to do that just for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a much more clean option than overriding `ToString`, this is better than what I hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

.NET uses the result of `ToString` to display the variable value when it is an `object`. So simply overriding `ToString` would do:

```
public override string ToString() => this.Name;
```

If you have no control over the class, putting a watch on the `Name` property will do too of course. (Use `theInstance?.Name` to be safe for null references)